# Why can't I access this ng-model variable in my controller?

Tags: angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/ntszE/

```
<input type="text" placeholder="0" ng-model="deposit" value="4" />&#8364; 
alert('begin test');
alert($scope.deposit);
alert('end test');
```

What am I doing wrong in binding the input value to a scope variable?

Comment: Define a controller for your HTML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to access the `$scope` in the controller. Check out the modification of your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lpiepiora/ntszE/2/

Basically you have to define a controller

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.deposit = 4;
    $scope.showValue = function() {
        alert($scope.deposit);
    };    
};
```

and then bind it using the `ng-controller` directive: `ng-controller="MyCtrl"`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a controller defined -

The `$scope` isn't exposed to any javascript out there. If you want to access it you need to get it. You can do something like this:

```
var scope = angular.element('input').scope();
alert(scope.deposit);
```

Comment: `var scope = angular.element('input').scope()` is actually enough, no need to wrap the selector in jquery ;)